# Project Odin - Web Dev 101 - Fundamentals Part 2 - Snarky Robot

Tags: javascript

In this lesson, there’s an external link to a lesson with exercises at the end. I’m working on the final exercise and I can’t quite figure out why my code is not working. Here is the prompt:

> A Snarky Robot
>
> Write code that asks the user what their favorite number is and then
>   responds according to the following guidelines:
>
> If the number is 42, the response should be “Yay! That’s my favorite
>   too!” If the number is less than 42 the response should be: “Eh,
>   that’s OK but X would be even better” for this response X should be
>   the number that they guessed + 1 If the number is higher than 42 the
>   response should be: “LAME. That number is too large!”

This is my code:

```
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number');
let x = number++;

if (number = 42) {
  response = "Yay! That's my favorite too!";
} else if (number < 42) {
  response = "Eh, that's OK but " + x + " would be even better";
} else {
  "LAME. That number is too large!";
}

console.log(response);
```

I’ve tried a few different things but the second test (prompt response “15”) keeps failing. It responds with the first option rather than the second. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `==` for comparison, not `=`!!!

Comment: Think about when the user responds to the prompt; is what is coming back a number or a string? Try converting the string to a number in order to perform mathematical calculations against it.

Comment: I have tried that, but this is the error I get: "ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at eval:12:13
    at eval
    at new Promise
"

Comment: @NikhilPatel You should define it outside your if blocks

Comment: If by `let x = number++;`, you are trying to store `number + 1` in `x`, it is wrong. It stores number in x and then increments number by 1.

Comment: @NiK648 how would I fix that? I've posted this on the Project Odin forum and so far, nobody else has pointed that out or seems to think there's anything wrong with variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
let number = prompt("what is your favorite number");
let x = number++; // this will store original response in x and increment number by 1.

if (x == 42) {//use x to check conditions
    response = "Yay! That's my favorite too!";
} else if (x < 42) {
    response = "Eh, that's OK but " + number + " would be even better";// use number to set response
} else {
    response= "LAME. That number is too large!";
}
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to have been a couple things causing the error. This code resolved the errors and passed each test output:

```
let number = Number(prompt('what is your favorite number'));
let x = number + 1;

if (number == 42) {
  response = "Yay! That's my favorite too!";
} else if (number < 42) {
  response = "Eh, that's OK but " + x + " would be even better";
} else {
  response = "LAME. That number is too large!";
}

console.log(response);
```

Thanks for the help, everyone

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this is an assignment instead of a comparison

```
if (number = 42) {
```

It should be:

```
if (number == 42) {
```

Also, you have to define "response" outside the if block, or else it will be undefined in some cases.